# Formula to create formula in Excel and Google Spreadsheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, google-sheets

Is it some how possible to turn a "text string formula" in a cell, into a formula in another cell?

For example if I have a formula in A1 that creates this (without "=" in the beginning):

```
SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(B2;$A2;$B2);$A3;$B3);$A4;$B4);$A5;$B5);$A6;$B6);$A7;$B7);$A8;$B8);$A9;$B9);$A10;$B10)
```

And then run this formula in B1:

```
=FORMULABASEDONCELL(A1)
```

Or if there are any other ways to have a formula creating another formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Excel you will need this UDF in a module attached to your sheet:

```
Function FORMULABASEDONCELL(rng as string)
    FORMULABASEDONCELL = Application.Evaluate(rng)
End Function
```

---

Another method in Excel leverages an old formula with Named ranges.

Open the Name manager and add a new named range.

Name the range anything you want, for example: `EvalForm`.

Then in the range area put:

```
=EVALUATE(Sheet1!$A$1)
```

Where Sheet1!A1 is the cell in which the string resides.

Then in any cell put `=EvalForm`

Comment: Good you added it, I was considering adding this option since OP did not tag VBA. Additionally, placing the selection in `B1` and entering the relative version `=EVALUATE(A1)`in the name manager, permits to evaluate any text formula in the cell right to it. This is a magic trick, awaiting hopefully a day when `INDIRECT` will accept other than addresses ;)

Comment: Does not work in Google Spread Sheet, but thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to create a formula that works for Excel and Google Sheets, first, because it's not possible to create a formula by using built-in functions, second because custom functions for each application are written using a different language, VBA on Excel and Google Apps Script on Google Sheets.